# JBoss JNDI: how programatically binding works

Tags: jboss, jndi

I have an idea of how to use JNDI, with the `InitialContext` and binding objects to JNDI via configurations files used by the JNDI Binding manager. You can also bind objects to JNDI programatically. However this is the part I don't quite understand how JNDI works in JBOSS.

When JBoss first starts it binds the objects based on the configuration files. However when a JNDI name is binded programatically the JNDI name is binded after JBoss has started.

My question is, if JBoss were to be restarted, would the JNDI name be lost that was programatically binded?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you bound to.

If you bound into the java: namespace, the binding will disappear when JBoss exits, because it's not persistent.

If you bound into an LDAP namespace, the binding is persistent, because LDAP is a persistent store.

If you bound into a CORBA namespace, the binding is coterminous with the COSNaming service you bound to.

If you bound into an RMI namespace, the binding is coterminous with the Registry you bound to.

Comment: What if an object was bound to the Global namespace?

Comment: What global namespace?

Comment: Well when I use the JMX console to list the bound JNDI values using the JNDIView service. There is a 'java: Namespace' section and a 'Global JNDI Namespace'. Apparently global JNDI values can be accessed remotely and the java one can't